# add script src inside javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

In a project when I add update panel in master page, then my jquery effects in a different page don't work even though I added the js script src in master page. When I googled for this problem, I found one solution which is below

```
function EndRequestHandler(){        
//document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='js/Blood_preesure.js'>")
}
```

and then

```
function load(){
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
}
```

and call this function at body onload

```
<body onload="load()">
```

1. In my EndRequestHandler() function I want to call script src. 
   I tried it with document.write but after postback the whole page is blank and displays nothing.
2. When I add full function which is in my js file, then everything works, but I don't want to inline the code since it is considered good practice to externalise code.

Comment: Use [`ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2552td66(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Comment: i just want do it with javascript not to call from code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document write will not work here ,

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
 if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
  var fileref=document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
 }
 else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
  var fileref=document.createElement("link")
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
  fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
 }
 if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}


    function load(){
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
}

function EndRequestHandler(){
 loadjscssfile(yourfilename, 'js');
}
```

Comment: thanks vishal i got my solution from your method, ya its good thing to remove huddle from page.if you have any other idea to call src script then just share with us.thanks. @vishal

Answer (score 0):

That's because `document.write();` overwrites the document each time.

You can create a script element by `document.createElement('script')` and play with it, before finally **appending** it to the DOM